# Replace domain name string

Tags: php

I have URLs in my string like below:

```
subdomain.domain.com/ups/a/b.gif
www.domain.com/ups/c/k.gif
subdomain1.domain.com/ups/l/k.docx
```

Looking to replace all URL like below:

```
anydomain.com/ups/a/b.gif
anydomain.com/ups/c/k.gif
anydomain.com/ups/l/k.docx
```

In above string (URL + ups) is common to match. All URLs are started with either HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Have you looked into [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: remove tag name out of the title

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful you should upvote them, and mark as accepted the one answer that best answered your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in comments, the way to parse URLs is with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
<?php
$urls = [
    "http://subdomain.domain.com/ups/a/b.gif",
    "https://www.example.com/ups/c/k.gif",
    "https://subdomain1.domain.com/ups/l/k.docx",
];
$domain = "anydomain.com";
foreach ($urls as &$url) {
    $u = parse_url($url);
    $url = "$u[scheme]://$domain$u[path]" . (isset($u["query"]) ? "?$u[query]" : "");
}
print_r($urls);
```

Comment: this is the best answer.. never use regex when there is a native way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's too late...
For a single string:

```
$components = parse_url( $url);
return str_replace($components['host'], 'anydomain.com', $url);
```

Protocol in url required.
If urls are array - run above in a loop

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/(http|https):\/\/(?:.*?)\/ups\//i", "$1://anydomain.com/ups/", $old_string);
```

so for input string:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/ups/a/b.gif
https://www.domainX.com/ups/c/k.gif
http://subdomain1.domain.com/ups/l/k.docx
```

the output will be:

```
http://anydomain.com/ups/a/b.gif
https://anydomain.com/ups/c/k.gif
http://anydomain.com/ups/l/k.docx
```

Comment: Thanks @Hossam but it should also catch "/ups/" also. It should not work over "http://subdomain.domain.com/upss/" while replace

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg : updated the code to catch only url's with "/ups/" after the domain name

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as right & upvote ^__^

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make use of regular expressions.

An explanation of what's going on with the regular expression:

```
# /^(http[s]?:\/\/).*?\/(.*)$/
# 
# / starting delimiter
# ^ match start of string
# (http[s]?:\/\) match http:// or https://
# .*? match all characters until the next matched character
# \/ match a / slash
# (.*) match the rest of the string
# 
# in the replacement
# 
# $1 = https:// or https://
# $2 = path on the url

$urls = [
    'https://subdomain.example.org/ups/a/b.gif',
    'http://www.example.org/ups/c/k.gif',
    'https://subdomain1.example.org/ups/l/k.docx'
];

foreach($urls as $key => $url) {
    $urls[$key] = preg_replace('/^(http[s]?:\/\/).*?\/ups\/(.*)$/', '$1anydomain.com/ups/$2', $url);
}

print_r($urls);
```

> Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://anydomain.com/ups/a/b.gif
    [1] => http://anydomain.com/ups/c/k.gif
    [2] => https://anydomain.com/ups/l/k.docx
)
```